# C# Customize DateTime offset format in ToString()

Tags: c#, timestamp

Is it possible to produce an output like `2021-04-14 01:23:45.123456+0800` using `DateTime.ToString()`?

I've tried to use `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ffffff")` followed by some combination of `z`, `zz`, `zzz`, etc, but cannot seem to get the offset portion of the string to not contain the `:`.

i.e. it produces `2021-04-14 01:23:45.123456+08:00`, but I need the `+08:00` to be `+0800`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a [custom timezone format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#offset-z-format-specifier) that will give you the full timezone without the colon. The simplest solution (IMHO) is to just remove the colon and add the timezone manually:

```
dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ffffff") + 
  dt.ToString("zzz").Replace(":","");
```

Or you could add the time zone to the string format and remove the "last" colon:

```
s = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ffffffzzz");
s = s.Remove(s.LastIndexOf(':'),1);
```

Comment: Easy peasy.  Thanks for that.  Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Brute force is often a great solution.  As a bonus, if you add a one-line comment, the maintenance programmer who picks this up in two years will be able to understand such nice clear code.

Comment: @Flydog57 Or a descriptive function name: `DateToStringWithTimeZoneWithoutColon` :)

Comment: @DStanley: Oh, come on: `Dt2StrWTZnoCol`.  Every keystroke counts (sorry, I work on an old and sometimes ratty codebase :-) )